# Display 24 hour time with 0's

Tags: swift, datetime, time

I'm trying to fix my time display. I have it currently to show as 24 hour but doesn't show the `0`'s so it'll show `1:5` instead of `01:05`

```
override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let dateTime = Date()
    let cal = Calendar.current
    let dfm = DateFormatter()
    dfm.dateFormat = "MMM"


    let time = String(cal.component(.hour, from: dateTime)) + ":" + String(cal.component(.minute, from: dateTime))

    let month = dfm.string(from: dateTime)

    let date = String(cal.component(.day, from: dateTime))  + " " + month

    timeNow.text = time
    dateNow.text = date .uppercased()

    self.dateTimeView.alpha = 1

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {


        UIView .transition(with: self.dateTimeView, duration: 0.5, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {self.dateTimeView.alpha = 0}, completion: nil)

    }
```

How do I format the time to show the leading `0`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to know about `DateFormatter`, but are only using it for formatting the month. You can use it to format other things too, like days, hours, and minutes.

```
let dateTime = Date()
let cal = Calendar.current
let dfm = DateFormatter()
dfm.dateFormat = "dd MMM" // this is the format of the date string you need

let date = dfm.string(from: dateTime).uppercased()

dfm.dateFormat = "HH:mm" // this is the format of the time string you need

let time = dfm.string(from: dateTime)

timeNow.text = time
dateNow.text = date
```

Comment: thank you so much, I havent been able to find anything anywhere on how to fix this.

Comment: Don't forget to set the dateFormatter locale to `"en_US_POSIX"` otherwise it will be affected by the user device locale and settings.

Comment: @LeoDabus I got the impression that this date *should* be affected by locals because it is set as the test of a label.